# Postgresql 10 pg_basebackup not backing up pg_control file

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to administrating postgresql 10 database so please bear with me (I'm from Oracle background). I was hoping a kind soul could point me to the right direction with our current problem.

We use pg_base to backup our current production system and for some reason since a couple of days ago pg_base has stopped backing up the database's pg_control file as well as postgres.conf which ofcourse renders the backup useless for restoration.

Below is the command that we use to initiate the backup

```
 /usr/bin/docker exec -i --user postgres asf-db1 pg_basebackup --wal-method=fetch -D /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/master_backup/latest -P -v --format=tar
```

The logs does not indicate anything suspicious and the issue only became apparent when I did a test restore.

Below is an extract of the backup logs

```
pg_basebackup: initiating base backup, waiting for checkpoint to complete
pg_basebackup: checkpoint completed
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log start point: 6/BF000178 on timeline 1
      0/1519047 kB (0%), 0/1 tablespace (...ta/master_backup/latest/base.tar)
 397408/1519047 kB (26%), 0/1 tablespace (...ta/master_backup/latest/base.tar
)^M1019400/1519047 kB (67%), 0/1 tablespace (...ta/master_backup/latest/base.
tar)^M1565927/1565927 kB (100%), 0/1 tablespace (...ta/master_backup/latest/b
t/base.tar)^M2164615/2164615 kB (100%), 0/1 tablespace (...ta/master_backup/l
p/latest/base.tar)^M2751015/2751015 kB (100%), 0/1 tablespace (...ta/master_b
r_backup/latest/base.tar)^M3061585/3061585 kB (100%), 0/1 tablespace (...ta/m
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log end point: 6/C0000050
pg_basebackup: base backup completed
Backup completed at: Wed 14 Nov 18:00:32 GMT 2018
```

Comment: That is weird. Permissions on the files are OK? `pg_basebackup` will always send `pg_control` last, so could it be that you are running out of space and the file is incomplete? That would cause an error though.

Comment: yes both files are owned by postgres and space is not a problem either and the rest of the datafiles and wal files can be found in the backup.

Comment: Hard to debug without examining your system. One hard core way to debug this is to `strace` the database walsender process that handles the backup and see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. The issue is fixed now it actually originated from the fact that the backup script was cronned multiple times in parallel. It was from an automated salt configuration.